# Remove Preloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some problem to remove preloader from my html template when i remove code from html file and js file preloader removed but also slideshow not showing up, so please provide proper way to remove preloader from my website, here is the code

Html page code
http://metroz.in/K/

```
<!-- Preloader  -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

and here was js file script
http://metroz.in/K/js/custom.js

```
 $win.load(function(){
            $('#status').fadeOut(defaults.speedAnimation);
            $('#preloader').delay(defaults.speedAnimation)
               .fadeOut(defaults.speedAnimation/2, function() { 
                that.fSize();
                that.activate();
                that.sliders();

                setTimeout(function(){
                    that.fMiddle();
                }, 10);
                setTimeout( function(){
                    that.fNum();
                    $('.layer').height(
                        $doc.height()
                    );
                }, defaults.speedAnimation/2);

                that.chars();
                that.bars();
                that.histLine();
                that.headerScroll();
                that.ytVideo();

                if (!onMobile){
                    $win.stellar({
                        horizontalScrolling: false
                    });
                }

            });
```

Comment: I can not see where you are removing preloader ? make js fiddle or improve your answer, so we can answer you proper.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :    `$("#preloader").remove();` to remove the div.

Comment: it will simply remove preloader won't do anything else.and since status is inner div to preloader it will also be removed.

Comment: you are right preloader removed after removing <div id="preloader"> tag but main problem is slideshow its not working.

Comment: then better you ask another question or change it the provide some info about your html also.